# Emacs: How remove lines that not contain some text

Tags: emacs

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

Suppose I has text:

```
aaaa 1111 zzzz
bbbb 1111 wwww
cccc 2222 yyyy
dddd 1111 vvvv
eeee 2222 rrrr
```

How remove lines that not contain **2222**.

I want to use built-in capabilities of Emacs (without write custom elisp script).

The result must be:

```
cccc 2222 yyyy
eeee 2222 rrrr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
M-x keep-lines RET 2222 RET
```